# Como puedo obtener permisos de escritura en ATOM

Tags: angularjs-2.0, atom-editor

¿Como puedo darle permisos a la ejecución de ATOM para que pueda crear carpetas?

[image: Situacion]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te paras en el directorio donde queres escribir y ejecutas el comando con root:

> chmod 755 .

Eso da permisos al usuario, al grupo y al resto, de lectura y ejecución.
Si queres escribir en otra carpeta vas a tener q hacer los mismo.

Comment: Lo que aparece en la imagen no es la terminal del Mac. Sino la del entorno de desarrollo de atom. Se aplica ese comando en la shell de atom también?

Comment: Ese comando se puede ejecutar tanto en la terminal de mac como en linux. Calculo q desde la terminar de atom se podrá. Si no te deja ejecutar por falta de permisos vas a tener q ejecutarlo con un usuario root (poniendo `sudo` adelante del comando y la pass de admin). Si no, podes ejecutar ese comando desde la terminal de TU pc y no desde la de atom.

Comment: Vale logre hacerlo, en la propia terminal hice un sudo y me pdio la pass desde ahi. Gracias por la ayuda